# Can I install Ubuntu on a Lenovo Ideapad A10?

Tags: system-installation, arm, ideapad

I have a Lenovo Ideapad A10 Android 4.2.2 netbook with a Rockchip RK3188 processor. The Rockchip RK3188 is a fast ARM SoC primarily designed for tablets. Unfortunately I soft bricked it and I wasn't unable to flash a recovery firmware since Lenovo does not support the device or maybe the developers are too lazy to create a recovery image for the device. Anyway I'm asking if I can install Ubuntu onto the device's internal storage?

I was able to run Slackware from the external SD card, but somehow it's quite buggy. I cannot install picuntu on it, and I think Lenovo does not allow it or there are some other reasons behind it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the hardware you have, but if it's bricked, why not go ahead with it, find out, and let us know about it?